# onkeyup event not firing with backup key on some devices

Tags: javascript, android, events, onkeyup, backspace

I have a javascript function that uses the `onkeyup` and `onchange` events to update some texts when the user changes the value of some input boxes. The update function works on the client side.

It works well on most browsers, including Chrome for Windows, but in Chrome for and Android pressing the backspace key doesn't fire the `onkeyup` event.

The `onchange` works well when the focus moves to another input, but it is not intuitive. The `onchange` event on the form also fires when the focus changes.

I don't like this:

- The user types a few characters -> the feedback is shown in real time (good)
- The user types the wrong character -> an error message is shown (good)
- The user presses backspace to remove the wrong character -> the error message is still there (BAD)

Any idea on how to get the update in real time after pressing backspace in all the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM input event that is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.

According to the Mozilla developer documentation there is basic support for this in all mobile and desktop browsers including Internet Explorer from version 9. [Mozilla developer documentation for Input Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)

At the moment as far as I can tell no browser provides any information yet regarding what has changed in the `<input>` element however this shouldn't affect your solution.